# Errors with string split

Tags: java, string

For some reason, I can get the split method to work. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong this this code:

```
String address = "0.0.0.0";
String [] adr = address.split(".");
System.out.println(address);
System.out.println(adr[0]);
```

I'm getting an index out of bounds error on the array accessor. Any ideas as to where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `split()` method expects a [regular-expression](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/JavaRegularExpressions), not a literal string, and the "." character has a special meaning in regular expressions.  To split on a literal "." character, you need to escape it so that the regex parser understands that's what you want.

Try it like this:

```
String [] adr = address.split("\\.");
```

Note that it is necessary to essentially escape it twice, because you want the regex parser to get the string "\.", which is actually "\\." when expressed as a string literal.  The "\\" resolves to a literal "\" character, so the regex parser is given "\.", which it then resolves to a literal "." character.

Also note that the stackoverflow parser appears to want to unescape certain sequences beginning with a "\", making this post confusing to edit.

Comment: thnks a lot :), i'd the same problem

Answer (score 4):

```
String address = "0.0.0.0";
String [] adr = address.split("\\.");
System.out.println(address);
System.out.println(adr[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

"." is a special character in regular expressions, and the argument to split is a regular expression. Escape it with . (i.e. "\\.").

Comment: should be "\\." since "." is not an escapable character in java

Comment: That's what I thought I wrote :-)